# How to preprocess fetched redux data for a React Native component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a react-native application built with expo.

It's a budgeting app. I am trying to display a pie chart of the types of expenditure for the given month.

My logic is as follows:

- Retrieve expenditures from redux via a dispatch() in useEffect
- Push the expenditure along with other fields to an array that will be supplied to the pie chart.
- Supply to Pie chart with that array as a prop.

What I'm experiencing:

- Retrieve expenditures from redux via dispatch() in useEffect
- Attempt to push expenditure with other fields to data array.
- Try and supply this array to Pie chart.
- Pie chart renders completely blank. (Logging the array at this point shows it's empty also)
- (Logging the array in the useEffect hook show's the non empty array)

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, AsyncStorage, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {getExp, clearExp} from './../actions/expActions.js';
import _uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId';
import { getRecurrExp } from '../actions/recurrExpActions.js';
import { PieChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";

export default function Report() {

  const expR = useSelector(state => state.expR)
  const recurrExpR = useSelector(state => state.recurrExpR)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width

  const chartConfig ={
    backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
    backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
    backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
    decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    style: {
      borderRadius: 16
    },
    propsForDots: {
      r: "6",
      strokeWidth: "2",
      stroke: "#ffa726"
    }
  }

  var piePieces = [];

  const getAllExps = () => {
    dispatch(getExp())
    dispatch(getRecurrExp())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllExps()
    expR.catCounts.map(cat => {
        piePieces.push({value: cat.count / expR.cat * 100, name: cat.category, color: cat.category==="cat1" ? '#E38627' : '#C13C37' })
    })
    console.log(piePieces) //Log's a filled array
  },[])

  // Deprecated, saving for 
  const clearAsyncStorage = async() => {
      AsyncStorage.clear()
  }

  const clearExpTest = () => {
    dispatch(clearExp())
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        {
          <PieChart
            data={piePieces}
            width={220}
            height={220}
            chartConfig={chartConfig}
            accessor="value"
            backgroundColor="transparent"
            paddingLeft="15"
            absolute
          />
        }
        {console.log(piePieces)} //Logs []
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffe6',
  },
  main: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this has something to do with re-rendering your component. Since you're pushing onto `piePieces` and not reassigning it will not re-render.

I also recommend to use useSate for piePieces to circumvent this exact problem.

Add useState to your imports

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
```

Top of your component define piePieces

```
const [piePieces, setPiePiecse] = useState([]);
```

You can use `forEach` instead of `map` since map returns a new array with the returned values

```
expR.catCounts.forEach(cat => {
  setPiePieces([...piePieces, {value: cat.count / expR.cat * 100, name: cat.category, color: cat.category==="cat1" ? '#E38627' : '#C13C37' }])
})
```

Comment: This looks like it may have fixed my issue. It's given rise to an issue with the pie chart component however. I will try and fix it with the information you've given me and will confirm your answer as correct shortly.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: The pie chart data prop expects an array, having implemented your suggestions it seems to be recieving a JS object. Any ideas why that might occur?

Comment: Have a look at setPiePices again, I forgot to add square brackets ;) It should work now.  `setPiePieces([...piePieces, {value: cat.count / expR.cat * 100, name: cat.category, color: cat.category==="cat1" ? '#E38627' : '#C13C37' }])`

Comment: Solved a problem that's been driving me nuts for about 3 days. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in future, Bloatlords answer is correct but will give rise to an async issue with setting state in a for each loop.

In order to fix this, the correct way to set state is:

```
setPiePieces(piePieces => [...piePieces, {value: ((cat.count / expR.cat) * 100),
                                          name: cat.category,
                                          color: (cat.category.localeCompare("cat1") ? "green" : "yellow"),
                                          legendFontColor: "black", legendFontSize: 15}
])
```